# Data Source and Delegate Options

Tags: ios, swift

when creating a table view, ViewController class adopts "UITableViewDelegate" and "UITableViewDataSource" protocols. To create a table view, we have to benefit from methods of these protocols. I understood this.

However, when creating a table view, we also choose tableview-data source and tableview-delegate options and match them with ViewController class by dragging. These are performed in storyboard file.

Why is this match process important ?

Why do we perform this match process ?

Comment: Imagine you have many view controllers and every view controller has a table view. This matching process as you say will help to connect which table view is associated with which view controller.

Comment: At very least you have to implement the `UITableViewDataSource` to tell the tableView how many rows you need to display and what the cell for each row should be. If you need to know what cell is been tapped by the user etc. then you will need to implement and `UITableViewDelegate`.  Read Apple's documentation to understand what each protocol does and why you need it.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to conform to both protocols and you don't need to set the `delegate` and `dataSource` in `Storyboard`, it can be done programatically as well.

You only need to do these if you are working with a `UITableView` in a `ViewController` that is not subclassing `UITableViewController`. `UITableViewController` automatically takes care of conforming to both protocols for you.

You need to set up the `delegate`/`dataSource` to a certain `ViewController`, because the system needs to know, which class' `delegate`/`dataSource` methods it needs to call when setting up the table view. If you have several view controllers with table views inside them in the same `Storyboard`, without setting up the delegate/dataSource to the current view controller, the system wouldn't know which class it needs to call for which tableview.

Conformance to `UITableViewDelegate` protocol is optional, if you only need to display data on a table view, but don't need user interaction with it, you only need to conform to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol. This is needed in order to set up the number of sections/cells in the table view and to set up the content of these as well.

Comment: Even you you work with a UITableViewController you don't need to have it be the data source and delegate of the tableview.

Comment: Thank yo so much. I state that ı cannot understand purpose of matching process ,but almost everybody sends links of protocols. You explained the purpose very great.

Comment: @Goktug -  Sorry for the link but i though you can get detail info there so gave you link to the official documentation.